# Basic Flask app not running (TypeError: required field "type_ignores" missing from Module)

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest, flask, virtualenv

I have a very basic flask app with dependencies installed from my requirements.txt. All of these dependencies are installed in my virtual environment.

requirements.txt given below,

```
aniso8601==6.0.0
Click==7.0
Flask==1.0.3
Flask-Cors==3.0.7
Flask-RESTful==0.3.7
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.0
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.10.1
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
# psycopg2-binary==2.8.2
pytz==2019.1
six==1.12.0
# SQLAlchemy==1.3.4
Werkzeug==0.15.4
python-dotenv
requests
authlib
```

My code in NewTest.py file,

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, abort, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return jsonify({
        'success': True,
        'index': 'Test Pass'
    })



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

When I run the app through,

```
export FLASK_APP=NewTest.py
export FLASK_ENV=development
export FLASK_DEBUG=true

    flask run
or flask run --reload
```

I get the following error,

```
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Feb/2020 12:43:40] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/projects/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 36, i
n reraise
    raise value
  File "/projects/NewTest.py", line 3, in <module>
    app = Flask(__name__)
  File "/projects/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 559, in _
_init__
    self.add_url_rule(
  File "/projects/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 67, in wr
apper_func
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/projects/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1217, in 
add_url_rule
    self.url_map.add(rule)
  File "/projects/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/routing.py", line 1388, in add
    rule.bind(self)
  File "/projects/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/routing.py", line 730, in bind
    self.compile()
  File "/projects/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/routing.py", line 794, in compile
    self._build = self._compile_builder(False).__get__(self, None)
  File "/projects/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/routing.py", line 951, in _compile_builder
    code = compile(module, "<werkzeug routing>", "exec")
TypeError: required field "type_ignores" missing from Module
```

Can anyone please point out what am I missing or doing wrong and how can I fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The bug was fixed in [werkzeug 0.15.5](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/changes/#version-0-15-5). Upgrade from 0.15.4 to to a later version.

Comment: But What is the problem with 0.15.4 ?

Comment: @Ahmed in the changelog linked https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/issues/1551

Answer (score 20):

I solved the error by simply executing the following line of code on the terminal:

```
sudo pip3 install --upgrade ipython
```

Comment: This worked for me, except a package google.colab was keeping the ipython version down since it wasn't compatible. ```pip3 uninstall google-colab`` and then your line fixed it for me.

Answer (score 7):

[werkzeug](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug) library can have issues with different python versions.

First of all, upgrade the werkzeug library to be the latest, then try again.

```
pip3 install --upgrade werkzeug
```

If that didn't work, I presume you may be using python version which kind of creates the whole issue.

You can always create a virtualenv [[Install, Create, and Activate](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/)] with a specific python version where werkzeug won't cause you this issue.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
pip uninstall Flask
```

then

```
pip install Flask
```

and

`pip uninstall Werkzeug`

then

`pip install Werkzeug`

Answer (score -1):

I had the error in django shell, it seems there is a bug in ipython. finally, I decided to remove ipython temporary until bug fix

```
pip uninstall ipython
```

[more info](https://bugs.python.org/issue35894)