# Python: TypeError: required field "type_ignores" missing from Module in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have been having issues with my jupyter notebook for a few days. I didn't fix them at the time but have decided to now. Earlier whenever I executed anything in the jupyter notebook, It showed a lengthy list of errors in the terminal(not in the notebook). I tried the same in jupyterlab but again, the same error. I upgraded my ipykernel and somehow it started working again.But this time it only executes a few statements such as `print(hello world)`

I tried using a few other things like this:

```
a = 1
b = 2

a+b
```

But it gave me this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/lib/python3.8/codeop.py in __call__(self, source, filename, symbol)
    134 
    135     def __call__(self, source, filename, symbol):
--> 136         codeob = compile(source, filename, symbol, self.flags, 1)
    137         for feature in _features:
    138             if codeob.co_flags & feature.compiler_flag:

TypeError: required field "type_ignores" missing from Module
```

I tried other things like importing a module but the same error. I am using Ubuntu 20.04 with python 3.8.2. What do I do? Here are all the installed libraries:

```
absl-py==0.9.0
aiohttp==3.6.2
altgraph==0.17
appdirs==1.4.4
apptools==4.5.0
apturl==0.5.2
argon2-cffi==20.1.0
asgiref==3.2.10
astroid==2.4.2
astunparse==1.6.3
async-timeout==3.0.1
attrs==19.3.0
autobahn==20.7.1
backcall==0.2.0
bcrypt==3.1.7
beautifulsoup4==4.9.1
bleach==3.1.5
blinker==1.4
blis==0.4.1
Brlapi==0.7.0
bs4==0.0.1
cachetools==4.1.0
catalogue==1.0.0
certifi==2020.6.20
cffi==1.14.1
chardet==3.0.4
chrome-gnome-shell==0.0.0
click==7.1.2
cloudpickle==1.3.0
colorama==0.4.3
command-not-found==0.3
configobj==5.0.6
cryptography==2.8
cupshelpers==1.0
cycler==0.10.0
cymem==2.0.3
Cython==0.29.20
dbus-python==1.2.16
decorator==4.4.2
defer==1.0.6
defusedxml==0.6.0
discord.py==1.3.4
distlib==0.3.1
distro==1.4.0
distro-info===0.23ubuntu1
Django==3.0.8
docker-py==1.10.6
docker-pycreds==0.2.1
duplicity==0.8.12.0
entrypoints==0.3
envisage==4.9.2
Faker==0.9.1
fasteners==0.14.1
fastzbarlight==0.0.14
filelock==3.0.12
Flask==1.1.2
future==0.18.2
gast==0.3.3
google-auth==1.19.2
google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.1
google-pasta==0.2.0
grpcio==1.30.0
gym==0.17.2
h5py==2.10.0
httplib2==0.14.0
idna==2.8
ipykernel==5.3.4
ipython==5.5.0
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
ipywidgets==7.5.1
isort==4.3.21
itsdangerous==1.1.0
jedi==0.17.1
Jinja2==2.11.2
joblib==0.15.1
json5==0.9.5
jsonschema==3.2.0
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-client==6.1.3
jupyter-console==6.1.0
jupyter-core==4.6.3
jupyterlab==2.2.5
jupyterlab-server==1.2.0
Keras==2.4.3
keras-models==0.0.7
Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.2
keyring==18.0.1
Kivy==1.10.1
kiwisolver==1.2.0
language-selector==0.1
launchpadlib==1.10.13
lazr.restfulclient==0.14.2
lazr.uri==1.0.3
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.3
lockfile==0.12.2
louis==3.12.0
lxml==4.5.2
macaroonbakery==1.3.1
Mako==1.1.0
Markdown==3.2.2
MarkupSafe==1.1.0
matplotlib==3.3.1
mccabe==0.6.1
mistune==0.8.4
mixer==6.1.3
monotonic==1.5
multidict==4.7.6
murmurhash==1.0.2
nbconvert==5.6.1
nbformat==5.0.7
netifaces==0.10.4
notebook==6.1.3
numpy==1.17.4
oauthlib==3.1.0
olefile==0.46
opencv-python==4.2.0.34
OpenTimelineIO==0.12.1
opt-einsum==3.2.1
packaging==20.4
pandas==1.0.5
pandocfilters==1.4.2
paramiko==2.6.0
parso==0.7.0
pathlib==1.0.1
pexpect==4.6.0
pickle-mixin==1.0.2
pickleshare==0.7.5
Pillow==7.0.0
plac==1.1.3
plotly==4.9.0
preshed==3.0.2
prometheus-client==0.8.0
prompt-toolkit==3.0.6
protobuf==3.12.2
psutil==5.5.1
ptyprocess==0.6.0
pyaaf2==1.2.0
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pycairo==1.16.2
pycparser==2.20
pycups==1.9.73
pyface==7.0.1
pygame==1.9.6
pyglet==1.5.0
Pygments==2.6.1
PyGObject==3.36.0
PyInquirer==1.0.3
PyInstaller==3.6
PyJWT==1.7.1
pylint==2.5.3
pymacaroons==0.13.0
PyNaCl==1.3.0
pyparsing==2.4.7
Pyphen==0.9.5
pyRFC3339==1.1
pyrsistent==0.16.0
python-apt==2.0.0+ubuntu0.20.4.1
python-dateutil==2.7.3
python-debian===0.1.36ubuntu1
pytz==2019.3
pyxdg==0.26
PyYAML==5.3.1
pyzmq==19.0.1
qtconsole==4.7.6
QtPy==1.9.0
regex==2020.7.14
reportlab==3.5.34
requests==2.24.0
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
requests-unixsocket==0.2.0
retrying==1.3.3
rsa==4.6
scikit-learn==0.23.1
scipy==1.4.1
seaborn==0.10.1
SecretStorage==2.3.1
selenium==3.141.0
Send2Trash==1.5.0
simplegeneric==0.8.1
simplejson==3.16.0
six==1.12.0
sklearn==0.0
soupsieve==2.0.1
spacy==2.3.2
sqlparse==0.3.1
srsly==1.0.2
syllables==0.1.0
system-service==0.3
systemd-python==234
tensorboard==2.3.0
tensorboard-plugin-wit==1.6.0.post3
tensorflow==2.3.0
tensorflow-cpu==2.2.0
tensorflow-estimator==2.3.0
tensorflow-hub==0.7.0
tensorflowjs==2.0.1.post1
termcolor==1.1.0
terminado==0.8.3
testpath==0.4.4
text-unidecode==1.2
thinc==7.4.1
threadpoolctl==2.1.0
toml==0.10.1
tornado==6.0.4
tqdm==4.48.2
traitlets==4.3.3
traits==6.1.1
traitsui==7.0.1
txaio==20.4.1
typing-extensions==3.7.4.2
ubuntu-advantage-tools==20.3
ubuntu-drivers-common==0.0.0
ufw==0.36
unattended-upgrades==0.1
unity-tweak-tool==0.0.7
urllib3==1.25.8
usb-creator==0.3.7
vtk==9.0.1
wadllib==1.3.3
wasabi==0.7.1
wcwidth==0.2.5
webencodings==0.5.1
websocket-client==0.57.0
websockets==8.1
Werkzeug==1.0.1
widgetsnbextension==3.5.1
wrapt==1.12.1
xkit==0.0.0
yarl==1.5.0
```

Comment: https://github.com/aiidateam/aiida-core/issues/3559 - this might help you

Comment: I accepted it. Stack overflow will make you wait over a day to give the bounty though

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As stated here
https://github.com/aiidateam/aiida-core/issues/3559 This might be due to ipython 5.8.0 incompatible with Python 3.8 issue.

Comment: `pip install --upgrade ipython` fixed the issue for me

Comment: Thanks. `conda update ipython` worked in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try these advices [Basic Flask app not running (TypeError: required field "type_ignores" missing from Module)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60140174/basic-flask-app-not-running-typeerror-required-field-type-ignores-missing-fr)

If it does not help please provide output from

```
pip freeze
```