# TypeError: required field "type_ignores" missing from Module

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

Note: I have read [Python: TypeError: required field "type_ignores" missing from Module in Jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63519761/python-typeerror-required-field-type-ignores-missing-from-module-in-jupyter), which contains a similar problem. However, I am still stuck.

Problem: I have just updated from Python 3.7.5 to Python 3.8.5. However, when I run code in Jupyter Notebook, the following error message is displayed:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/opt/python@3.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/codeop.py in __call__(self, source, filename, symbol)
    139 
    140     def __call__(self, source, filename, symbol):
--> 141         codeob = compile(source, filename, symbol, self.flags, 1)
    142         for feature in _features:
    143             if codeob.co_flags & feature.compiler_flag:

TypeError: required field "type_ignores" missing from Module
```

I get this message when I run code like

```
i = 1
```

or code like

```
import numpy as np
```

or code like

```
from platform import python_version

print(python_version())
```

I have read [Python: TypeError: required field "type_ignores" missing from Module in Jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63519761/python-typeerror-required-field-type-ignores-missing-from-module-in-jupyter), which contains a similar problem. However, the poster in that question had an outdated ipython version. I did a

```
pip freeze
```

and found that I had the newest version (7.2.0), which means that the solution to that problem does not apply to this problem.

Below is some extra information if you need:

What I tried: I first tried to revert from Python 3.8 to Python 3.7. This is because the error message mentioned that the error was coming from /usr/local/opt/**python@3.8**/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/**python3.8**/codeop.py I tried to do this by downloading pyenv and python 3.7 again (I had python 3.7 before but it had disappeared) and setting the python version to 3.7.5 by configuring the .zshenv file. However, that caused jupyter notebook and even programs like emacs to stop working with messages like

```
command not found: jupyter
```

and

```
command not found: emacs
```

I finally did it by downloading the python 3.7.5 pkg file from the python website:

```
python --version
```

output:

```
Python 3.7.5
```

However, when I launch Jupyter Notebook, I still get the same error as before ("TypeError: required field "type_ignores" missing from Module"). I am afraid that installing Python 3.8 did some permanent damage.

This is my .zshenv file configuration:

```
export SACAUX=SACHOME/aux
export SACHOME=/usr/local/sac
export PATH=${PATH}:${SACHOME}/bin
export PATH=SACHOME/bin
export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:SACHOME/bin
export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:SACHOME/bin:HOME/.pyenv/bin
export PATH=~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.5/bin:${PATH}
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages
```

FYI, (If this is useful), All of the packages I need (tensorflow, numpy, scipy) are in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages, a python 3.7 folder, so I had to explicitly set PYTHONPATH to /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages so that Python can find the packages to import.

What are some fixes to solve this "TypeError: required field "type_ignores" missing from Module"?

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this? I'm facing the same problem as well

Comment: Thanks Nour for calling this to my attention, I was not able to fix the problem but by taking random actions successfully rolled back to Python 3.7. I now use conda environments so that if this happens I can throw the environment away and create a new one.

Answer (score 5):

Tried fixing it with werkzeug update and it did not work. On ubuntu 20.04.2

Found this [issue](https://github.com/pyeve/eve/issues/1331#issuecomment-765227255) for a package I am not sure I am using but mentions updating iPython.

```
pip3 install ipython --upgrade
```

it then updated some python packages but not others. And now it seems to work.

Comment: The information helped me, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I don't mean to revive a dead question, but I saw that someone commented asking for an answer to this recently and this is the top result when searching for this problem.

I had this issue and apparently it was an issue with the Werkzeug package implementation in an older version, I fixed it by updating it from version 0.15.4 to 1.0.1 using pip:

```
pip install werkzeug --upgrade
```

this should fix your issue; if you'd like to know which version you're on, launch a `terminal` and launching the Python interactive terminal using the command `python`:

```
import werkzeug
werkzeug.__version__
```

Comment: I came across this after updating pexpect as per https://askubuntu.com/questions/1106943/syntaxerror-regarding-async-when-attempting-to-run-jupyter-in-python-3-7 I attempted to upgrade but no success: $ pip3 install werkzeug --upgrade
Collecting werkzeug
  Using cached Werkzeug-1.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (298 kB)
Installing collected packages: werkzeug
Successfully installed werkzeug-1.0.1